# Fast speed test but slow downloads

Tags: networking

I had to get a new modem, but I kept the same router.
The connection speed for all of my machines went up to where it should be, except for my Ubuntu machine.

The speed test looks right on target with everything, but when I actually need to download files from Dropbox or Google Drive, it chugs at 3.7 MB/sec, whereas before I was getting 10 MB/sec with a bum modem.

Comment: Downloading depends not only on the systems at your end of the line, but also on the systems along the line and at the other end. For  example, if the server from where you want download is busy, it will send data at a lower rate. Pllease try again a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is consistency (both happens to all hosts or during the whole day).  Is every site you go to slow with this system?  If not, then you might try to look at the path to the slow hosts with mtr (trace route).  If it's only certain times of day, but the other computers are not affected, then there may be some network dynamics that are too complicated for me to know what to tell you to try, although check the system's busy level and network throughput with a system monitor in that case.

If it's consistent, can you try file transfers from one of the other local systems to see if maybe it's the network port that specific machine is using?  Maybe there's a hardware issue.  Obviously, if you have a speed problem within your network, then that's a totally different issue.

Finally, if it's fine locally and consistent, recheck your network settings and ensure you don't have a VPN or Proxy setup that could be adding additional overhead to the connection.

Comment: I would hope Op knows if they have a VPN installed :) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a really off the wall possible answer.

I would suggest you change the MTU value on your machine from 1500 down to a value 1400 or so.  Sometimes a router and wherever URL you are going to have a segment that is small and your packet has to be broken up.  This can cause a problem with slow downloads.

If you run the command "ifconfig" or "ip addr" to get the current MTU.  Using networkmanager you can change the MTU even if you use a DHCP address.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what.. spectrum came out and it had nothing to do with my end.  Their equipment outside the house got messed up, and they had to replace it all.  Nothing to see here, move along.  LOL